# SQL Display the parent title of the product with the child title

Tags: sql, xml

Good day,

I have a woocommerce eshop in which I do not use variants ... all products are simple. But for partner shops I need to create XML with variable products.

I have products that are not published are "hidden" (custom post status).

I also have "parent_sku" for custom field products where my parent product is specified.

I have a SQL code that extracts all the necessary products from the database and also sku and parent_sku

I would need to modify the SQL code to display the post_title of the parent product for the product variant.

I enclose my SQL code and some pictures

```
    SELECT 
    wp_posts.post_title AS title,
    wp_posts.post_excerpt AS shortdesc,
    wp_posts.post_content AS longdesc,
    wp_postmeta1.meta_value AS sku,
    wp_postmeta6.meta_value AS parent_sku,
    wp_postmeta2.meta_value AS price,
    wp_posts1.guid AS img,
    wp_postmeta5.meta_value AS mall,
    GROUP_CONCAT( wp_terms.name ORDER BY wp_terms.name SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS product_categories
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta1
    ON wp_postmeta1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    AND wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta2
    ON wp_postmeta2.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    AND wp_postmeta2.meta_key = '_regular_price'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta3
    ON wp_postmeta3.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    AND wp_postmeta3.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp_posts1
    ON wp_posts1.ID = wp_postmeta3.meta_value
    AND wp_posts1.post_type = 'attachment'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta5
    ON wp_postmeta5.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    AND wp_postmeta5.meta_key = 'mall'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta6
    ON wp_postmeta6.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    AND wp_postmeta6.meta_key = 'parent_sku'


LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
    ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
    ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
LEFT JOIN wp_terms
    ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'hidden') AND wp_postmeta5.meta_value = 'yes'
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY sku ASC
```

my code show this table

[IMG_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUngY.png)

I need to display a spreadsheet like this

[IMG_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e4Mf.png)

thank you for any help <3

Comment: Fields in SQL dos no correspond to title names in picture.
BTW, SKU is the 4th field in SQL and 5th in Picture.
I supose you want to add the 2nd field in the picture into the SQL, isn't it?

Comment: @Biggum yes you are right second column where to show parent_title is not in SQL code .. I want to add it there

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. But first take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @Biggum Sorry I don't understand English. Want to see a real sql result without blurry text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first approach would be something like this. I can not test it cause I have no sample DB

Make your sample SQL a subquery of a new query (it has parent SKU)
Join with another subquery which contains parent SKU and the data you want.
The main Query selects the fields in the desired order.

```
SELECT baseSQL.title p_title, 
           parentSQL.title AS p_parent_title, -- second field in picture
           baseSQL.shortdesc AS p_shortdesc,
           baseSQL.longdesc AS p_longdesc,
           baseSQL.sku AS p_sku,
           baseSQL.parent_sku AS p_parent_sku,
           baseSQL.price AS p_price,
           baseSQL.img AS p_img,
           baseSQL.mall AS p_mall,
           baseSQL.product_categories AS p_categories
    FROM
      ( SELECT 
          wp_posts.post_title AS title,
          wp_posts.post_excerpt AS shortdesc,
          wp_posts.post_content AS longdesc,
          wp_postmeta1.meta_value AS sku,
          wp_postmeta6.meta_value AS parent_sku,
          wp_postmeta2.meta_value AS price,
          wp_posts1.guid AS img,
          wp_postmeta5.meta_value AS mall,
          GROUP_CONCAT( wp_terms.name ORDER BY wp_terms.name SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS product_categories
        FROM wp_posts
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta1
          ON wp_postmeta1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku'
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta2
          ON wp_postmeta2.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta2.meta_key = '_regular_price'
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta3
          ON wp_postmeta3.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta3.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
        LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp_posts1
          ON wp_posts1.ID = wp_postmeta3.meta_value
          AND wp_posts1.post_type = 'attachment'
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta5
          ON wp_postmeta5.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta5.meta_key = 'send'
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta6
          ON wp_postmeta6.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta6.meta_key = 'parent_plu'

        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
          ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
          ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
          AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms
          ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
        WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        OR wp_posts.post_status = 'hidden') AND wp_postmeta5.meta_value = 'yes'
        GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
        ORDER BY sku ASC
      ) baseSQL

    LEFT JOIN
      (
        SELECT 
          wp_posts.post_title AS title,
          wp_postmeta1.meta_value AS sku
        FROM wp_posts
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta1
          ON wp_postmeta1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku'
      ) parentSQL

    ON baseSQL.parent_sku = parentSQL.sku 
    AND baseSQL.parent_sku > 0
    GROUP BY baseSQL.sku
```

Check the performance of this, maybe moving grouping and ordering outside will become in a better performance.

I don't propose to make a subquery in a nested JOIN within original LEFT JOINS because I cannot test it and from here and now, I can't image how would react this "cross joining" with postmeta1 and postmeta6.

I recommend to implement some trigger and have sku and parent_sku fields in table wp_posts and you could do simple subquery with the table itself.
In mySQL there is no hierarchical queries (until I know mySQL) like in Oracle, but maybe this helps to improve your query.
It's up to you.

Sorry If this don't work on copy/paste, It's just an approach.

Edited with final functional SQL

Comment: hi thank you very much for your help. I get the following error when I enter the code.
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
    wp_posts.post_title AS title,
    wp_postmeta1.meta_va' at line 51"

Comment: Added a missing "FROM" to main SQL. Syntax issue.
But without sample DB, hard to try if there is some other running issue.
Are you a beginner in SQL?

Comment: I made several times from SQL, but I overlooked this error (beginner).

This works. but from 255 products I have 44000 products
this is because each parent product adds a child product title

I can join products by adding "GROUP BY baseSQL.sk" ... now I see 255 products.
But I still see the child product name in the rainbow (parent_post_title) column.

Comment: I'm affraid I don't understand where you are stuck. I Understand you solved cartesian operation of the tables and recovered the number of results.
But don't get the parent product name?

Comment: Products that do not have a parent_post have a different product title in the second column (parent_post_title). 
I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: At the end I added the following code "AND baseSQL.parent_sku> 0"
The code works brilliantly. I just don't know if it's right.

Thank you very much for your help. It wouldn't work without you

Comment: Could you post the complete SQL please? So I'll can edit mine for a better quality answer.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

my fully functional code

```
 SELECT baseSQL.title p_title, 
           parentSQL.title AS p_parent_title, -- second field in picture
           baseSQL.shortdesc AS p_shortdesc,
           baseSQL.longdesc AS p_longdesc,
           baseSQL.sku AS p_sku,
           baseSQL.parent_sku AS p_parent_sku,
           baseSQL.price AS p_price,
           baseSQL.img AS p_img,
           baseSQL.mall AS p_mall,
           baseSQL.product_categories AS p_categories
    FROM
      ( SELECT 
          wp_posts.post_title AS title,
          wp_posts.post_excerpt AS shortdesc,
          wp_posts.post_content AS longdesc,
          wp_postmeta1.meta_value AS sku,
          wp_postmeta6.meta_value AS parent_sku,
          wp_postmeta2.meta_value AS price,
          wp_posts1.guid AS img,
          wp_postmeta5.meta_value AS mall,
          GROUP_CONCAT( wp_terms.name ORDER BY wp_terms.name SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS product_categories
        FROM wp_posts
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta1
          ON wp_postmeta1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku'
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta2
          ON wp_postmeta2.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta2.meta_key = '_regular_price'
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta3
          ON wp_postmeta3.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta3.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
        LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp_posts1
          ON wp_posts1.ID = wp_postmeta3.meta_value
          AND wp_posts1.post_type = 'attachment'
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta5
          ON wp_postmeta5.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta5.meta_key = 'send'
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta6
          ON wp_postmeta6.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta6.meta_key = 'parent_plu'

        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
          ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
          ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
          AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms
          ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
        WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        OR wp_posts.post_status = 'hidden') AND wp_postmeta5.meta_value = 'yes'
        GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
        ORDER BY sku ASC
      ) baseSQL

    LEFT JOIN
      (
        SELECT 
          wp_posts.post_title AS title,
          wp_postmeta1.meta_value AS sku
        FROM wp_posts
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta1
          ON wp_postmeta1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
          AND wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku'
      ) parentSQL

    ON baseSQL.parent_sku = parentSQL.sku 
    AND baseSQL.parent_sku > 0

    GROUP BY baseSQL.sku
```

Comment: Yes, this code works correctly.
Thank you again for your help. I encountered another problem ... I need to extract images from the database and they are stored as a list of ids in one cell ie "200, 201, 202" in the second table I know based on id display url, but it doesn't work if I have more IDs in the cell

Comment: I asked you the statement to complete my answer with the final code, not to revoke my solution by yours...upvoting yourself is a little bit...ugly
Btw, with your las question, you have to publish one image or all of the images in the list?
It seems logical to retreive cell value as is and loop over the values in each execution of recordset loop